# is there any two alignment in one text box (SSRS-2016)?

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SSRS 2016. I have a textbox that returns an amount. I am trying to set two alignment in one textbox. $      2,786.sucs as  $ symbol on left and amount in right alignment. is there a better way to do ? as I am concatenating $, Spaces and amount but this action expands in some amount.

Comment: Split currency symbol and number in two textboxes

Comment: Thank you, Niktrs. i tried by adding a rectangle and then place two text boxes on it. but when i export into excel one column(amount) is appearing in 3 columns.

Comment: Depending your design you maybe could omit using a rectangle for the 2 cells. If you have any issue, make a post and I ll try to resolve it.

Comment: can you illustrate what you are getting now and what you want to achieve?